# How do I setup Selenium webdriver on RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rubymine

I have to learn how to user Selenium Webdriver in RubyMine
I have no idea how to install Selenium gem.
I have downloaded Selenium gem, but what is next? how do I install or bind to my RubyMine IDE?
I used to work a lot with Java, Ruby and RubyMine is completely new tools for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found it! simple type command in command line `gem install selenium-webdriver`

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine is an IDE. Selenium Webdriver is a gem. When you write your Ruby code, you will have a require of the selenium webdriver gem. On your system, you will need to have the Selenium gem installed.

See the following URL for more information. It does matter which web browser you intend to be running Selenium against.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings